# How to copy an array to apend to another array?

Tags: arrays, jolt

I need to construct the array and append it to an existing array.

My input json is:

```
{
  "restaurantId": "ZZ4ORJDY3E",
  "chainId": "RLR932KI",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "itemName": "Small Barqs",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Mozzz",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And, I am trying to get the output as:

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "field1" : "RLR932KI",
    "field2" : "ZZ4ORJDY3E"
  }, {
    "field1" : "Small Barqs",
    "field2" : 2
  }, {
    "field1" : "Mozzz",
    "field2" : 1
  } ]
}
```

The spec I have now:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "chainId": "array[0].field1",
      "restaurantId": "array[0].field2",
      "orderItems": {
        "*": {
          "itemName": "array[&1].field1",
          "quantity": "array[&1].field2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The above spec gives me:

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "field1" : [ "RLR932KI", "Small Barqs" ],
    "field2" : [ "ZZ4ORJDY3E", 2 ]
  }, {
    "field1" : "Mozzz",
    "field2" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by doing a two stage shift:

1. Create an array of arrays
2. Then flatten array of arrays.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      //create array arrays
      "chainId": "[0].[0].field1",
      "restaurantId": "[0].[0].field2",
      "orderItems": {
        "*": {
          "itemName": "[1].[&1].field1",
          "quantity": "[1].[&1].field2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      //flatten array of arrays
      "*": {
        "*": "array.[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```